Getting Error from ModelBuilder (calculate values)
I want to remove the last 7 character from parsepath (%Value%)
what is wrong with this code?



There are a couple of issues with the set up of the Calculate Value tool. Here is my model:

Here is the correct set up of the tool:

The key differences are I am passing the inline substitution into the function as a parameter and explicitly stating the data type of its output. You should always do that otherwise the tool you are connecting to does not know what it is getting.
